# copy perl object ref

Tags: perl, object, reference, copy, clone

How do I copy/clone an object ref that has been "blessed"? For example, I have

```
my $html = HTML::PullParser->new(file => $file, text => 'text');
```

then I want to iterate over that `$html` object multiple times via

```
$html->get_token();
```

So what I tried to do is to copy the object first:

```
use Clone qw(clone);
my $html1 = clone($html);
my $html2 = clone($html);
```

Then I tried to iterate over the new objects:

```
while ($html1->get_token()) {
    # do something
}
while ($html2->get_token()) {
    # do something else
}
```

But clearly the object is NOT copied over (or at least not copied over in the right way) so that I do not get any iteration in either loop.

What is the right way to copy this object?

Thx!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, cloning an object requires knowledge of its internal structure.  [Clone](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Clone) just copies the internal structure, which works on plain data structures and many objects, but fails on more complex objects in unpredictable ways.

In this case, the [HTML::PullParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aPullParser) object is reading from a filehandle.  The cloned copy gets a reference to the *same* filehandle, so they are not independent.

Some objects have a `clone` method, but HTML::PullParser does not.  You can create multiple objects:

```
my $html1 = HTML::PullParser->new(file => $file, text => 'text');
my $html2 = HTML::PullParser->new(file => $file, text => 'text');
```

and they will be independent.  Or are you trying to clone the object in the middle of parsing?  Perhaps you can explain why you think you need to clone the parser and we can suggest a better approach.

Comment: I know I can run multiple parses as your suggested. The file is huge so parsing takes a long time. I thought copying, if there is a clean way to do it, would save time. In particular, if I want branch out in the middle of iteration as you suggested, then create multiple new parsers won't help.

Comment: @Zhang18, I recommend finding some way of approaching the problem that doesn't involve cloning the parser.  For example, you might save the tokens returned by `get_token` in an array, and then loop over the array several times.  If you explain what you're trying to accomplish (maybe in a new question), perhaps we can help you find a better approach.

Comment: saving tokens to an array is a great idea that somehow escaped me. Thanks a lot.